# ¿Qué es "darse unas perdidas"?

Tags: modismos, cuba

Hace un par de días, en nuestro chat [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), [Theia comentó](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39276283#39276283):

> @fedorqui como estas? **te das unas perdidas** de todos los chats.. :)

En España esta expresión no la usamos y yo no la entendí. ¿Qué quiere decir? Theia es de Cuba, ¿se usa en algún otro lugar?

En el DLE lo único parecido que se encuentra es:

> [**dar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BrtRK35)
>   8. tr. Suponer, declarar, considerar. *Lo doy POR visto, POR inocente. U. t. c. prnl. Se dio POR perdido, POR muerto.*

Comment: Viendo solamente el título pensaba que se podría referir a lo mismo que con "hacer una perdida", es decir, una llamada perdida, "dar un toque al móvil". Luego ya por contexto veo que se refiere a otra cosa. ¿Será algo parecido a "hacer mutis por el foro"?

Comment: Podría ser algo como "hacer una **perdida** al móvil"? Es decir, como cuando ves que tienes pendiente una llamada sin contestar. Lo mismo Theia se refiere a que Fedorqui andaba respondiendo (llamadas) "perdidas" en los chats de todos los stacks que participa (los Stacks overflow, este, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El diccionario de americanismos tiene [una definición](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=darse) que encaja con el contexto y se usa en Cuba:

> **darse una perdida.** loc. verb. *Cu, PR, Ve.* Dejar *una persona* de frecuentar a alguien o un lugar.

Así que creo que sí, se refiere a que de repente desapareces del chat y dejas de responder a los mensajes. Hacer mutis por el foro, vamos.

Comment: *Mutis por el foro* siempre me causa gracia. *Darse una perdida* no lo usamos en Argentina pero encaja bien con el patrón de *darse unas vueltas* o *darse un chapuzón*.

Comment: ¡Grande! De hecho [Theia explicó](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39297849#39297849) luego en el chat que _"darse unas perdidas" seria el equivalente de "estar perdido" o "no dejarse ver", en el sentido de que hace rato no apareces por el chat :) , aqui es bastante usado_, así que confirmadísimo que es esto.